# How to split value of dict on two parts

Tags: java, groovy

I have

```
def dict = [some_key : ['a', 'bc', 'd']]
```

I would like to split `bc` to `b` and `c`, so after splitting dict will be looks like this:

```
dict = [some_key : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Is there any way to do this with build-in methods?

Comment: have you tried any regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here You go:

```
def dict = [some_key : ['a', 'bc', 'd']]
dict.some_key = dict.some_key.collect { it.collect{ it } }.sum()
println dict
```

`collect` invoked on `String` will return a `List` of characters.

Comment: Wow! What's happend here :D Groovy is better then Python. I'm falling in love. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that clear? Do you need any further clarification?

Comment: Yes. I will modify it a little bit -> adding findAll to filter elements, ('a', 'bc', 'd') was just example,  I have much more complicated datas :P , but you helps me a lot. :)

Comment: Ok, so what You'd like me to explain?

Comment: or `dict.collectEntries(dict) { [it.key, it.value.collect { it.collect() }.sum() ] }`

Comment: My solution based on Opal's answer: `dict['some_key'] = dict['some_key'].findAll{ it.contains("String_to_split")}.collect{ it.split("regexp") }.sum() + dict['some_key'].findAll{ !it.contains("String_to_split")}`